# как работает Thread

Tags: java, наследование

Здравствуйте!
Решил провести эксперимент с Thread'ом, - какой именно run будет запущен, но почемупроисходит именно так, не знаю. Суть в следующем:
создаю дочерний класс от Thread, и "как-бы определяю" в нем два метода run, - первый с внутренним анонимным классом Runnable передаю в конструктор, а второй метод run просто переопределяю, вот так:

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
    MyThread (){
        super(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){ //=================== first run
                System.out.println("first run");
            }
        }, "MyThread");
        System.out.println(" сработал конструктор");
        start();

    }
    @Override
    public void run (){ //=================== second run
        try {
            for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
                System.out.println(i+" second run. Текущий поток "+Thread.currentThread());
                Thread.sleep(500);  
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e ){  e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Дальше запускаю в основном потоке и срабатывает run именно второй, который был переопределен, а не тот который был передан в конструктор. Извините, если вопрос глупый, но кто может объяснить почему так происходит? Или подскажите где об этом можно почитать. Спасибо!

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyThread();
        try {
            for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
                Thread.sleep(1000); 
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e ){ e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Это ещё ничего, вы попробуйте в переопределённом `run` запустить `super.run()`.

Answer (score 6):

В отдельном потоке выполняется метод `run()` у класса Thread, про это написано [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html). И если посмотреть в реализацию [OpenJDK Thread](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/5ea0024ba765/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#l720), то можно увидеть:

```
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

Т.е. если вы передали в конструкторе `Runnable` то будет вызвать именно он. Вы же переопределили метод `run()` и соответственно у вас он делает что-то своё.

Comment: да, но я и в конструкторе Runnable передал, и класс перегрузил.

Comment: @MisterSmith, еще раз: вы переопределили исходный метод `run`, нет его больше для потока, а ваш метод `run` ничего не знает о `Runnable` из конструктора